# How to get rid of 'Unable to free colormap, pallette is still selected' error?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have been working bugs out of a python script for color gradients, but I get this obscure error when closing out of the python console that says:

```
Unable to free colormap, pallette is still selected
```

Then, I get a popup saying "Python has stopped responding". I think this means it crashed, but i have no clue. I have no idea why it happens, but it seems random so far.

I have tried many different versions of if statements, math, and execution in the past, but nothing has worked to fix it.

```
import turtle, random, os
turtle.colormode(255)
turtle.bgcolor(0, 0, 0)
curX = 0
curY = 0
curZ = 0
while True:
    x = random.randint(0, 255)
    y = random.randint(0, 255)
    z = random.randint(0, 255)
    success = False
    XD = 0
    YD = 0
    ZD = 0
    while success == False:
        if curX < x:
            curX = curX + 1
        elif curX > x:
            curX = curX - 1

        if curY < y:
            curY = curY + 1
        elif curY > y:
            curY = curY - 1

        if curZ < z:
            curZ = curZ + 1
        elif curZ > z:
            curZ = curZ - 1

        turtle.bgcolor(curX, curY, curZ)
        os.system("cls")
        print(x),
        print(y),
        print(z)
        print(curX),
        print(curY),
        print(curZ)
        if curX == x:
            print("X")
            XD = 1
        if curY == y:
            print("Y")
            YD = 1
        if curZ == z:
            print("Z")
            ZD = 1

        if XD + YD + ZD == 3:
            success = True
```

When I close out of the program, I expect it to just close out with no errors whatsoever, 100% of the time, but every now and then, it will throw up that "Unable to free colormap, pallette is still selected" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an event-driven environment, we can't simply do `while True:` and expect things to work.  Doing such effectively blocks some events from firing.  The window closing event can be tricky -- more so that than turtle is sometimes able to handle, so we may need to drop down to the tkinter level to do it properly.

Below is my rework of your code to use a timer event to replace the infinite loop, and a window closing handler to catch the window closing event.  The handler tries to stop your inner loop and timer event cleanly, then finishes closing out the window.  Plus some other changes for style:

```
from turtle import Screen
from random import randint
from os import system

screen = Screen()
screen.colormode(255)
screen.bgcolor(0, 0, 0)

curR = 0
curG = 0
curB = 0

running = True

def window_closing():
    global running
    running = False
    screen.ontimer(screen.bye, 500)

def switch_color_target():
    global curR, curG, curB

    r = randint(0, 255)
    g = randint(0, 255)
    b = randint(0, 255)

    success = False

    RD = False
    GD = False
    BD = False

    while running and not success:
        if curR < r:
            curR += 1
        elif curR > r:
            curR -= 1
        else:
            RD = True

        if curG < g:
            curG += 1
        elif curG > g:
            curG -= 1
        else:
            GD = True

        if curB < b:
            curB += 1
        elif curB > b:
            curB -= 1
        else:
            BD = True

        screen.bgcolor(curR, curG, curB)

        system("cls")

        print(r)
        print(g)
        print(b)

        success = RD and GD and BD

        if success:
            print("R")
            print("B")
            print("G")
        else:
            print(curR)
            print(curG)
            print(curB)

    if running:
        screen.ontimer(switch_color_target, 250)

switch_color_target()

canvas = screen.getcanvas()
root = canvas.winfo_toplevel()
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", window_closing)

screen.mainloop()
```

I am not using the same operating system as you so I can't throughly test this -- give it a try to see if it solves your issues.

Comment: I have tested your code, but it didn't really work. I do kinda get what you are saying though. Are you saying i need a bit of code to call to when closing the window so it closes safely? Or are you saying i need code to make it run for only so long? I'm sorry if i don't get what your trying to say, just got back into python a month ago.

Comment: @SPP3000, I guess I'm saying you need a bit of handler code to be called by the event loop when the window is closing and you need loop in an event-friendly way.